# How to read Directory with folders containing JSON files : Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I keep getting this file while reading from directory (folders with json files). I used :

```
// sc : An existing SparkContext.
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData")
df.show()
```

The Error :

```
java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:173) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:279) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

My File system looks like :

testData - directory which has 3 folder (00, 01, 02) each has 1 file/folder

```
testData/00/temp1.json.gz 
testData/01/temp2.json.gz 
testData/02/temp3.json.gz
```

I am using spark 1.5 Is there anything wrong with the way I am reading ?

Comment: You know sending me an anonymous request on Quora doesn't make me want to answer this question. https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-read-Directory-with-folders-containing-JSON-files-in-Spark?srid=agpP&share=8d582ea1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not efficient but you can `sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData/*/*")`

Comment: why it's not efficient?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219